# Pyspark job being stuck at the final task

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

The flow of my program is something like this: 
1. Read 4 billion rows (~700GB) of data from a parquet file into a data frame. Partition size used is 2296 
 
 
2. Clean it and filter out 2.5 billion rows 
 
3. Transform the remaining 1.5 billion rows using a pipeline model and then a trained model. The model is trained using a logistic regression model where it predicts 0 or 1 and 30% of the data is filtered out of the transformed data frame. 
 
4. The above data frame is Left outer joined with another dataset of ~1 TB (also read from a parquet file.) Partition size is 4000 
 
5. Join it with another dataset of around 100 MB like 
 
`joined_data = data1.join(broadcast(small_dataset_100MB), data1.field == small_dataset_100MB.field, "left_outer")` 
 
6. The above dataframe is then exploded to the factor of ~2000 
`exploded_data = joined_data.withColumn('field', explode('field_list'))` 
 
7. An aggregate is performed 
`aggregate = exploded_data.groupBy(*cols_to_select)\
        .agg(F.countDistinct(exploded_data.field1).alias('distincts'), F.count("*").alias('count_all'))` 
 
 There are a total of 10 columns in the `cols_to_select` list. 
 
8. And finally an action, `aggregate.count()` is performed.

The problem is, the third last count stage (200 tasks) gets stuck at task 199 forever. In spite of allocating 4 cores and 56 executors, the count uses only one core and one executor to run the job. I tried breaking down the size from 4 billion rows to 700 million rows which is 1/6th part, it took four hours. I would really appreciate some help in how to speed this process up Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operation was being stuck at the final task because of the skewed data being joined to a huge dataset. The key that was joining the two dataframes was heavily skewed. The problem was solved for now by removing the skewed data from the dataframe. If you must include the skewed data, you can use iterative broadcast joins (https://github.com/godatadriven/iterative-broadcast-join). Look into this informative video for more details https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zg7NTw-kTQ